# How to use is.na to identify NA, " ", "" etc

Tags: r, vector, na, missing-data

I have 2 problems:

**Problem 1:** I am trying to work out how to identify any common missing value formats like NA, " ", "".

I thought is.na would identify all of these formats, can someone point me in the right direction for what I need to do here?

**Problem 2:** I need to count the NA, " " and "" values and list the position for all of them.

Ive tried:

````
```{r, echo=TRUE,include=TRUE}
sum(is.na(DF))
which(is.na(DF))
```
````

but it only counts the NA values (16) and tells me which value position they are in.

However, I also happen to know there are  10 values in my dataset that are missing and their format isnt NA, its " ", so the total for missing values should be 26 and I should get the value position for all of them.

I tried using something like:

```
sum(is.na(DF, na.strings=c("NA"," ","")))
```

But I got this error:
Error in is.na(DF, na.strings = c("NA", " ", "")) :
2 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1

Any ideas on what to do here would be amazing as well.

Thank you!

Comment: ```na.strings=c()``` only works while reading tables into R with the ```read.``` functions. 
Maël's answer should work for your problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is.na` only detects NA values, not `" "` nor `""`. You can convert `" "` and `""` to NA using `gsub`, and then use `is.na`:

```r
v = c(NA, "", " ", "A")
gsub("^$|^ $", NA, v)
# [1] NA  NA  NA  "A"

sum(is.na(gsub("^$|^ $", NA, v)))
# [1] 3

which(is.na(gsub("^$|^ $", NA, v)))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Explanation: `^$` captures empty string (`^` defines the beginning of the string and `$` the end). `^ $` captures a string with one space (with the same anchors having the same purpose), and `|` is the OR operator.

Comment: Or could use `nzchar` `v[!nzchar(trimws(v))] <- NA`

Comment: Maël - Thank you! Are you able to explain what the ("^|^$" part does? Im not sure im following that part sorry

Comment: And is V the dataframe? Thank you again!

Comment: See my edit. Yes the V is the dataframe. Since you did not provide a reproducible datafame, i created the vector V. But it would also work with a dataframe.